# Indetermined system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the system $$\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{x_i}=3$$ for $N>2$.
The main aspect that confuses me is the general $N$ and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: the middle term is not exactly "linear"...
For $N=3$ an obvious solution is $x_i = 1 \quad\forall\ i$. Try to find general solutions for small $N$ and see what happens as $N$ increases.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. How is this a linear problem?

Comment: Changed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x+\frac 1x \ge 2$ if $x$ is positive.  If you add the two equations there are no solutions for $N \gt 3$ and all $x_i=1$ is the only solution for $N=3$ unless negative values are allowed for $x$. If negative values are allowed you can't say much.

Answer (score 0):

By Vieta's formulas the solutions of this system are the families of roots of polynomials
$$
x^n+ a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots +a_n=0,
$$
where $a_1=-3$ and $a_{n-1}/a_n=-3$. Taking arbitrarily coefficients $a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}$, you will get all solutions.